what's the logic in 憋久了？
i saw a sentence 不开心的事情在心里憋久了是会生病的
i take it it means "if u bottle up the sadness (or "sad things") u're gonna be sick"
憋 means "to bottle up" here.
okay, but i didn't understand two other things.

i know 久 means "long time" or "for a long time", but does it act like an adverb here or it's more like a suffix/grammatical construction? i mean, there's quite strange character order in 憋久了， so 久 doesn't seem to be an adverb to me, i just don't understand how it works

了.


just 了. what is it in this case, why is it here and everything. is it a past tense indicator, so it turns out that the whole sentence is in the past, or it's a part of construction or anything else, maybe?

I don't think Chinese has a very formal grammar, you can decomposed it as: Unhappy thing, in heart, bottle up, long, is, will sick, and re-composite the whole sentence based on your rationality: "is", 了, 的 doesn't have too much meaning to me, more like an emotional expression

憋久了 has the verb + complement + 了 structure where 久 is the complement. You can learn about this structure in this link.

Your phrase can be expressed like this:
如果你把不开心的事情在心里憋久了，有可能你会生病了。
(If you) hold on to unhappy thoughts for too long, that can cause (physical) illness.
We can state the opinion:
不开心的事情在心里憋久了是会生病的
unhappy things in mind hold for long time that can/will (cause) (physical) illness
Holding on to unhappy thoughts for too long can cause (physical) illness.
I would use this tentative form of can in the translation, to indicate possibility. will for 会 seems more assertive than can，but will also only indicates an assumption, not a certainty.
... 事情... 憋久
things ... hold long time
Holding on to ... for (a) long time
了：

is it a past tense indicator

No. It can't be that here. Nothing has happened. The speaker opines that, if you have dark thoughts for a long time, you may or will get sick. But you are not sick, I hope. Maybe you are just having a bad day.
了 can equally be used when talking about events which have not (yet) happened，or may never happen.
不开心的：unhappy
事情: things (here: thoughts, ideas)
心: mind, heart
在 。。。里： in
憋: hold on to, keep in
久: (for a) long time
了： indicates that the preceding phrase is finished
是会： that can
生病的: fall ill

憋 - hold back; suppress
憋久 - hold back/suppress long
久(adj) + 了 = too [adj]
憋久了 = hold back/suppress too long.
https://www.omeidachinese.com/le-zi-chinese-grammar-use/

entire sentence's logic: (((when)) unhappy things are a focal point and suppressed for too long it causes ((you)) to feel ill.
logic of the 憋久了:  憋 in context means suppressed, 久了 in context is similar to 太久了 aka a generic "too long a time", but altered in a way that makes sense as a compound verb phrase with suppressed.
Note these things may mean different things in other contexts, chinese is a very context heavy language and the exact meaning of characters//phrases is altered by the existing known information in the conversation.
